# Spring MVC Add and Modification doesn't work properly as I want

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

Currently in my project, addEmployee.jsp show properly when "Add Employee" or "Edit" is clicked, but when I try to hit submit button in "Add Employee" page, page return "Http status 500 Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException", or when I try to hit submit button in "Add Employee" page for update employee info, I will get "HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported"

The way I want is when I add a new employee or update the existing employee info, I will still using addEmployee.jsp page. If it is add a new one, all the field will be empty, otherwise, all the field will contain the existing information for update.

Here is the code for employee.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Employee List</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div align="center">
        <h1 style="background-color: lightgreen; color: darkgreen">Employee
            Page</h1>
        <table align="center" width="80%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
            <tr>
                <td align="center">
                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6" border="0" width="100%">
                        <tr bgcolor="lightblue">
                            <td align="left"><a
                                href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/employee/addEmployee"
                                style="background-color: lightblue;"> Add Employee </a></td>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6" border="1" width="100%">
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="8"
                                style="background-color: lightblue; color: darkgreen; font-size: 16pt"
                                align="center">Employee List</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr bgcolor="grey" style="color: white">
                            <th>No</th>
                            <th>First Name</th>
                            <th>Last Name</th>
                            <th>Job Title</th>
                            <th>Department</th>
                            <th>Salary</th>
                            <th>Edit</th>
                            <th>Delete</th>
                        </tr>
                        <c:forEach var="employee" items="${employeesList}"
                            varStatus="status">
                            <tr bgcolor="lightyellow">
                                <td><b>${status.index + 1}</b></td>
                                <td>${employee.firstName}</td>
                                <td>${employee.lastName}</td>
                                <td>${employee.jobTitle}</td>
                                <td>${employee.department}</td>
                                <td>${employee.salary}</td>
                                <td><a
                                    href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/employee/edit/${employee.id}">Edit</a></td>
                                <td><a
                                    href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/employee/delete/${employee.id}">Delete</a></td>
                            </tr>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And Here is the code for addEmployee.jsp page

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Add Employee</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div align="center">
        <h1 style="background-color: lightgreen; color: darkgreen">Add
            New Employee Page</h1>
        <table width="80%" align="center">
            <tr bgcolor="lightblue">
                <td align="left"><a href="listEmployees"
                    style="background-color: lightblue;">List Employee</a></td>
        </table>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div align="center">
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6" border="1" width="80%">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="8"
                    style="background-color: lightblue; color: darkgreen; font-size: 16pt"
                    align="center">Employee Information</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:form method="POST" action="updateEmployee">
                        <table width="100%">

                            <tr>
                                <td><form:label path="firstName">First Name</form:label></td>
                                <td align="left" width="70%"><form:input path="firstName" /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><form:label path="lastName">Last Name</form:label></td>
                                <td align="left" width="70%"><form:input path="lastName" /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><form:label path="jobTitle">Job Title</form:label></td>
                                <td align="left" width="70%"><form:input path="jobTitle" /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><form:label path="department">Department</form:label></td>
                                <td align="left" width="70%"><form:input path="department" /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><form:label path="salary">Salary</form:label></td>
                                <td align="left" width="70%"><form:input path="salary" /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </form:form></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the code for EmployeeController.java

```
package com.vincent.springmvc.controller;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.vincent.springmvc.model.Employee;
import com.vincent.springmvc.service.EmployeeService;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/employee")
public class EmployeeController {

    //Logger file
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmployeeController.class);
    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService employeeService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String welcomeEmployee(ModelMap model){
        model.addAttribute("name", "Hello World!");
        model.addAttribute("greetings", "Welcome to Spring MVC");
        return "hello";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/listEmployees", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listEmployees(ModelMap model){
        model.addAttribute("employeesList", this.employeeService.listEmployee());
        return "employee";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addEmployee", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView addEmployee(ModelMap model){
        return new ModelAndView("addEmployee", "command", new Employee());
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/updateEmployee", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String updateEmployee(@ModelAttribute("employee") Employee employee, ModelMap model){
        if(employee.getId() == 0)
            this.employeeService.insertEmployee(employee);
        else
            this.employeeService.updateEmployee(employee);
        model.addAttribute("employeesList", this.employeeService.listEmployee());
        return "employee";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/delete/{empId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String deleteEmployee(@PathVariable("empId") Integer empId, ModelMap model){
        this.employeeService.deleteEmployee(empId);
        model.addAttribute("employeesList", this.employeeService.listEmployee());
        return "employee";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/edit/{empId}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView editEmployee(@PathVariable("empId") int id, ModelMap model){
        return new ModelAndView("addEmployee", "command", this.employeeService.getEmployeeById(id));
    }
}
```

Here is the project structure
[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otQju.png)

and the rest of the code you can find in https://github.com/zhengye1/SpringMVC

Thank you for the help

Comment: maybe you miss a @ModelAttribute("employee") method in your class or remove the ("employee") part in your method

Comment: @jpprade you mean I should try remove ("employee") in updateEmployee method?

Comment: it should be inject like this : @ModelAttribute Employee in your controller or have method withe the annotation @ModelAttribute("employee")

Answer (score 0):

Kind of resolve for now.... but seems like not a very good idea, it is time to looking for good advice..

The way I fix is, in my controller class, I change the annotation in `updateEmployee` with following annotation `@RequestMapping(value = {"/updateEmployee", "/edit/updateEmployee"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)`. This because when I tracing the log, I realize somehow the server try to mapping the page called edit/updateEmployee, originally is not exists, that is why it raising the 504 error for update.

For adding issue is causing by the form, since the form return the null id, therefore when I try to compare the null object with 0, it raise the null pointer exception. The way I fix is, change that line to if `(employee.getId() == null)`, and also in `addEmployee.jsp` page, I add the this line to my form, `<form:hidden path="id" />`. That is resolve the issue.